# inline shadow without text

Tags: html, css

I applied shadow to one image but there is text into that image.When I apply the shadow to the image, the text is affected too.
I tried to carry the text out of the `div` but then the image broke.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSWxY.png

```css
.image{
    
    
object-fit: cover;
  display:flex;
  width:33.3%;
  height:320px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
.image:after{
    content: '';
    transition: opacity .4s ease;
    display: block;
    will-change: opacity;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 0,#000 99%,#000 100%);
    opacity: .8;

}

.haberr{
    
   position:absolute;
   color:white;
   margin-bottom:5px;
   bottom: 15px;
   left: 16px;

}
```

```html
<div class = 'image' >
  <div class= 'haberr'>   <h1>".$row['name']."</h1>".$row['author']."</div>
   <a href = 'https://www.alba.com.tc/".$row['linkname']."'>
   <img src = '".$row['photo']."' alt='alba' width='500' height='320' alt = ''>
   </a>
   
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to add `z-index:4;` to `.haberr` class, and it should be working. :)

Here is the fixed version :

```css
.image{
    
    
object-fit: cover;
    display:flex;
width:33.3%;
height:320px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
.image:after{
content: '';
    transition: opacity .4s ease;
    display: block;
    will-change: opacity;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 0,#000 99%,#000 100%);
    opacity: .8;

}

.haberr{
    
position:absolute;
z-index : 4;
color:white;
margin-bottom:5px;
bottom: 15px;
left: 16px;

}
```

```html
<div class = 'image' >
  <div class= 'haberr'>   <h1>".$row['name']."</h1>".$row['author']."</div>
   <a href = 'https://www.alba.com.tc/".$row['linkname']."'>
   <img src = '".$row['photo']."' alt='alba' width='500' height='320' alt = ''>
   </a>
   
  </div>
```